# IIS 7.5 Not Compressing Javascript: NO_MATCHING_CONTENT_TYPE

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, compression, javascript

I have IIS 7.5 set to compress all static files (the default), yet it does not compress .js (javascript) files. When I turn on failed request tracing for compression, the error I get for the compression is:

NO_MATCHING_CONTENT_TYPE

I read about this, and the only solution I saw posted was to make sure application/x-javascript (and not just application/javascript) is specified as a mimetype seen as 'static' content. So I adjusted my applicationHost.config to have this:

```
    <httpCompression>
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="5" />
        <scheme name="deflate" dll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

However, I still see the same error in failed request tracelogs: NO_MATCHING_CONTENT_TYPE. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `.js` files mapped to one of these MIME types (e.g. `application/javascript'), and not something else entirely, e.g.`text/javascript`.  (If you just issue a HTTP request using something like curl or wget against one of these files as a client, what MIME type is the server returning it as?)

Comment: I believe it is mapped properly, the response headers show application/x-javascript: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=345600
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 16:16:41 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Etag: "da4944d97978cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2011 20:18:30 GMT
Content-Length: 13598`